# left shift count >= width of type - adding UL or casting individually does not fix the issue

Tags: c++

I'm trying to do something very simple and I'm getting this warning. Here is what I have:

```
#define VERSION ( (unsigned long)( (CORE_ID << 32) + (PROTO_ID << 24) + (VERSION_ID << 16) + (RELEASE_ID << 8) + (HOTFIX_ID) ) )

unsigned long vern = VERSION;
```

I keep getting the warning left shift count >= width of type and nothing I did helped get rid of this message. I tried casting individually to unsigned int but that didn't help either.
All IDs are just regular #define's of just numbers.

I tried adding UL to the end of each number but that did not help either. I understand that this means my shifting results in overflow but I'm not sure how to remedy it, considering everything is defined as UL.
I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, any help is appreciated.

Thanks so much

Comment: What is the type of `CORE_ID`?

Comment: `CORE_ID << 32` --> `1ull*CORE_ID << 32`, same for `PROTO_ID`.  Even better, post all `#define` related to this like `CORE_ID`, etc.

Comment: #define HW 80   #define REV    5    #define CORE_ID  7 #define PROTO_ID   7 #define VERSION_ID  (HW+REV)     #define RELEASE_ID 07   #define HOTFIX_ID 01

Comment: "tried adding UL to the end of each number" is unclear.  Posting the code that failed is more useful than describing the code that failed.

Comment: Try `#define VERSION (  (1ull*CORE_ID << 32) + (1ull*PROTO_ID << 24) + (1ul*VERSION_ID << 16) + (1ul*RELEASE_ID << 8) + (1ul*HOTFIX_ID) )`

Comment: Maybe if you stopped using macros and used proper C++ variables with clear types instead, the problem would be clearer...

Answer (score 1):

That cast after all the calculations won't help; the problem is that the types being shifted are too small, and the answer is to increase their sizes. I don't want to type it all out, but here's the pattern:

```
#define VERSION ((unsigned long)CORE_ID << 32)
```

Converting `CORE_ID` to type `unsigned long` will probably fix the problem. If `unsigned long` is too small (i.e., it's 32 bits wide, which is the minimum allowed size), then change it to `unsigned long long`. In the original code, cast each of those things to `unsigned long`; once they all have type `unsigned long`, the result of combining them will also be `unsigned long`, and you won't need that initial cast.

Comment: Or use `uint64_t` (declaring constants with the `UINT64_C` macro if appropriate), since the nature of the field is such that it must be 64 bits wide, so mucking about with types without official sizes seems silly.

Comment: `unsigned long long` would be better. On 64-bit windows `unsigned long` is still 32-bit and the standard only says that `unsigned long long` has to be at least 64-bits

Comment: @ShadowRanger - `uint64_t` is not required to exist. For maximum portability, `uint_fast64_t` or `uint_least64_t` would be a better choice.

Comment: @PeteBecker: True. I've never encountered a system without it, but yeah, for maximum portability, stating your minimum requirement and letting the compiler handle it is good.